# Proving ratio of random variables is Cauchy random variable: Why partition like this?

Tags: probability

I'm a bit confused on why the following partition was taken. Why was it partitioned into two and why with y > 0 and then y < 0. Then the joint p.d.f. of the transforms is found by adding the two joint p.d.fs obtained from below. The whole thing just confuses me.

[image]

[image]